# How to prevent many downvotes

Tags: discussion, down-votes, specific-user, serial-voting

On the mathematics SE site there, yesterday, was a person who went on and disliked every single one of my posts. I don't know who that was, but I feel that this will continue if it does not stop now. Can I have any recommendations on how to deal with people like this? (I knew it was someone spamming because all the dislikes happened within 1 min or so even on my more popular questions). Is there a way I can see who this user was?

Comment: Did the person make unsolicited offers of goods or services? If not, that was not spam.

Comment: At least I am assuming that by "disliked" is meant "downvoted".

Comment: The daily script  should revert the serial downvotes.

Comment: @DanielFischer Could you have a look at the recent changes in my reputation please? I honestly dont know what to do.

Comment: You got a series of downvotes between 9:36 and 9:40 UTC today. Those I expect to be reverted by the script. You got other downvotes, which probably won't be reverted, since they seem not to be connected. For now just wait until the script runs.

Comment: @DanielFischer What do you mean reverted? What does that mean in this context? Also, is it possible if you tell me who the spam user was? Im sorry for asking so many questions as I have been on for a week and a half

Comment: @AAron Reverted in this context means "the system will pretend they never happened". No, nobody will tell you who the downvoter is. And once again, **this is not spam**. Spam is a serious problem of its own, using the word to mean anything we don't like is counterproductive.